# How to count distinct column values from one table for each database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I got this situation where there are several databases that have the same table name with distinct information.

I want to type a query where I can get the distinct values of a given column and then get the count for each database.table and each column value as follows:

Table: projects (found in each database):

```
status - quantity(DB1) - Quantity(DB2) - Quantity(DB3)
In progress - 147 - 141 - 135
Cancelled   - 2 - 1 - 4
Finished    - 45 - 52 - 64
```

How do I achieve that??

I have tried the following (and other workarounds):

```
SELECT p2012.STATUS AS 'Status',COUNT(p2012.STATUS) AS 'Quantity' ,COUNT(DB2013.STATUS) AS 'Quantity'
FROM DB2012.projects AS p2012, DB2013.projects AS p2013
GROUP BY p2012.STATUS
```

But I get the following with same quantities and big numbers:

```
status - quantity(DB1) - Quantity(DB2) - Quantity(DB3)
    In progress - 13447 - 13447 - 13447
    Cancelled   - 3434 - 3434 - 3434
    Finished    - 4344 -4344 - 4344
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Solved** With the help of Giancarlo Benítez:

```
(
SELECT '2012' AS 'year',A.InProgress AS 'InProgress',B.Restarted AS 'Restarted',C.Cancelled AS 'Cancelled',D.Finished AS 'Finished' FROM
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'InProgress' FROM DB2012.projects WHERE status='PRO') AS A,
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'Restarted' FROM DB2012.projects WHERE status='RES') AS B,
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'Cancelled' FROM DB2012.projects WHERE status='CAN') AS C,
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'Finished' FROM DB2012.projects WHERE status='FIN') AS D
)
UNION
(
SELECT '2013' AS 'year',A.InProgress AS 'InProgress',B.Restarted AS 'Restarted',C.Cancelled AS 'Cancelled',D.Finished AS 'Finished' FROM
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'InProgress' FROM DB2013.projects WHERE status='PRO') AS A,
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'Restarted' FROM DB2013.projects WHERE status='RES') AS B,
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'Cancelled' FROM DB2013.projects WHERE status='CAN') AS C,
(SELECT status, count(*) AS 'Finished' FROM DB2013.projects WHERE status='FIN') AS D
)
UNION
...
```

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: I know, but this is how I found it. I didn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do several querys for each one an the get it all together, something like:

```
select A.status, A.counts, B.status, B.counts 
from 
(select status, count(*) as counts from DB2012.projects where status = 'In progress') as A, 
(select status, count(*) as counts from DB2012.projects where status = 'Cancelled') as B;
```

This will get you something like

```
In progress - 123 - Cancelled   - 876
```

All in the same line, then you can process it o put it in a table, as you want.

Comment: Check for `group by` statement, it could be useful too.